# Cannot install Cairo for R on Red hat Linux 7.4

Tags: r, cairo, rhel7

I am trying to install "Cairo" for my R installation 3.4.4. I have looked at similar issues, however none of the suggestions resolve my issue. I get the following error when installing the package:

```
> install.packages("Cairo")
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Cairo_1.5-9.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 86982 bytes (84 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 84 KB

* installing *source* package ‘Cairo’ ...
** package ‘Cairo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... gcc -std=c99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=c99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=c99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=c99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking whether pkg-config knows about cairo... yes
checking for configurable backends... cairo cairo-ft cairo-pdf cairo-png cairo-ps cairo-xlib cairo-xlib-xrender
configure: CAIRO_CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng15 -I/usr/include/libdrm  
checking if R was compiled with the RConn patch... no
checking cairo.h usability... yes
checking cairo.h presence... yes
checking for cairo.h... yes
checking for PNG support in Cairo... yes
checking for ATS font support in Cairo... no
configure: CAIRO_LIBS=-lfreetype -lpng15 -lz -lXrender -lcairo -lXext -lX11  
checking for library containing deflate... no
checking whether Cairo programs can be compiled... configure: error: Cannot compile a simple Cairo program. See config.log for details.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Cairo’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib64/R/library/Cairo’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpmbjNVO/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("Cairo") :
  installation of package ‘Cairo’ had non-zero exit status
```

My issue is two-fold. Firstly following the failure of the installation, no "config.log" file is produced anywhere on the system, which makes it very hard for me to debug. Furthermore I believe I have the right packages installed namely:

cairo-devel.x86_64 and libX11-devel.x86_64

To give a bit of extra information, below is the sessionInfo for R. Thank you

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/local/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /usr/local/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.4
```